# Is there a way to get terminal data from Mac to python program

Tags: python-3.x, macos, terminal

I want to code a python program that records CPU temperature and Processor usage (especially power in Watts) from Mac terminal `sudo powermetrics`. Is there a way to do so? It is way too unrealistic and time consuming if I want to record the data myself.

Comment: @Philippe What is the command/package for that?

Comment: Sorry, it's subprocess : https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html